# Google Spreadsheet: vector-like operations on columns

Tags: math, google-sheets, calculated-columns

Imagine two columns `A,B` in Google Spreadsheet like

```
    A     B
1   1.0   1
2   1.5   1
3   3.0   2
4   2.0   1
5   2.5   2
```

With the function `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5;B1:B5)` I would get `15.5` by summing up the products of two cells (like`=sum(A*B)` if A and B would be vectors with 5 elements each). How can one get a similar function that sums up only the column-product where `B1:B5==2`, resulting `11`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this; here are two:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5,B1:B5,B1:B5=2)`

`=SUM(FILTER(A1:A5*B1:B5,B1:B5=2))`

Comment: both solutions work if you use `;` instead of `,` as separator between the arguments of the function.

Comment: Ah yes, in your locale it might be required to do that. Although I would have expected that your decimals would be written as eg `1,0`.

Comment: Indeed, my decimals use a comma but I didn't realize this as I am used to "scientific" decimals with dots. But thanks anyway...